# Can an XXE (XML External Entity) attack be carried out from within an SVG file?

Tags: xml, svg, xxe

Since SVG is built heavily if not entirely on XML, can one of the attacks that can be carried out through XML such as XXE injection be carried out from an SVG file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XXE vulnerabilities are all to do with the parser. If the parser that processes the SVG file grabs external entities without verification, then it is vulnerable.

For an example, see [this vulnerability in an Apache library](https://www.insinuator.net/2015/03/xxe-injection-in-apache-batik-library-cve-2015-0250/).